# Regex, match any character after match

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match the entire string when I have identified the middle part.

I have the string:

```
first:second:third:forth:fifth
```

I wish to match it when I write for example: `:third:`

I do not wish to match it when I write for example `:sixth:`

I've figured out the first half, been looking around for the regex to extend to include any character after the match.

[image]

Comment: Why not `.*:third:.*`?

Comment: @melpomene Whaaaat, I swear to god I tried that and it didn't work, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You want a look-ahead check:

```
(?=.*:third:).*
```

https://regex101.com/r/48Adar/1

Comment: Do you really need a look-ahead in this case?

Comment: @MuratK. No, this simple case is just as easily solved with `.*:third:.*`, as melpomene indicates. However, the look-ahead will come in handy as soon as there is more than one condition to be checked and the order of items in the subject is not predetermined. Like `(?=.*:third:)(?=.*:second:).*`